# Twilio click to call and gather digit

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I've developed a web that connect two persons into a call following this tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/click-to-call-node-express
and everything is working fine.

Now I need to gather 1 digit of the callee in order to execute a command.

Reading the Twilio documentation it seems I can't use Gather until the Dial verb is over, but this way the call is closed and the callee can't digit anything.

I tried this without success, the dial works fine but the digits callback is never executed:

```
twimlResponse.say(
    'Please wait for the other person to join the call'
  );

  twimlResponse.dial({
    timeLimit: 30
  })
  twimlResponse.dial(to_number)

  const gather = twimlResponse.gather({
    input: 'dtmf',
    timeout: 30,
    numDigits: 1,
    action: url // the url is the callback that should handle the digit entered
  });
```

Is it a limitation of Twilio? any workaround or alternative call strategy?

Comment: Hey Fabrizio, do you need to perform the gather on the end of the callee before they are connected, or during the conversation?

Comment: I need to perform the gather at the end of the call, as a final action the callee should perform after talking to the other party.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to send an `url` with the `number` you dial and have that URL respond with the TwiML you want to drive the interaction with the callee. From https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number:

> The 'url' attribute allows you to specify a url for a TwiML document
>   that will run on the called party's end, after she answers, but before
>   the parties are connected. You can use this TwiML to privately play or
>   say information to the called party, or provide a chance to decline
>   the phone call using `<Gather>` and `<Hangup>`.

So something like this:

```
const dial = twimlResponse.dial({
  timeLimit: 30
});
dial.number({
  url: urlToGather // respond to this URL with your <Gather> TwiML
}, to_number);
```

Comment: Thanks smarx, the solution doesn't fit to my needs because I need to gather the digit at the end of the call.

Comment: I'm not sure that can be done. [The action attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) seems most promising, but that seems specific to the "dialed party" (callee) hanging up.